# CE Image makes my logs sad by using xss_clean

Tags: ce-image, xss

Since updating to EE 3.4.0, I keep getting an annoying notification that there's new junk in the dev-logs. And there, I only find this ... which seems to be done by the almighty CE Image.

```
Deprecated function xss_clean() called in /var/www/html/svenskakakel.se/public_html/system/user/addons/ce_img/libraries/Ce_image.php on line 664.
From template tag exp:ce_img:pair in keramik/produkt.
Deprecated since 3.0. Use ee('Security/XSS')->clean() instead.
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

CE Image is supposedly for EE3 now, but, is it really? :)

I'm running PHP 5.6.24 (after downgrading from php 7 which, if you ask me, is not good for EE-enviroment yet).

Comment: Did you send them an email with a description of the issue?
You can also find the line in the plugin where xss_clean() is called and replace it with ee('Security/XSS')->clean()

Answer (score 2):

CE Image 3.0.1 has been released and should take care of those pesky deprecation notices.